# Angular 4 - first steps

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I started my coding looking a nice video on the internet, then the first line of code is not working.

What I did so far was to follow the instructions of the website:
https://cli.angular.io/

So I installed a preconfigured code, it is running with node, but this line does not work as I get the title displayed: "Welcome app", as you will see "app" is set in the app.component.ts script.

The issue is when I execute the page and I change the content of the input I don't see it reflected in the title (the text inside of h1):

```
<input type="text" name="title"  ngModel><br>

<h1>
  Welcome to {{title}}!!
</h1>
```

This code is in src/app/app.component.html 
And this is the code of src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

I tried also

```
 <input type="text" name="title"  [(ngModel)]="title"><br>
```

but it didn't work,

Any help, please?

Comment: Did you import `FormsModule` in @NgModule?

Comment: nop, I have no idea what is that, can you please give me a hand?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/DlA3SNjZxdCwipfB2GzS?p=preview See comment in app.ts

Comment: Thanks a  lot! it is working nicely now. Can you please move you response in the main thread so I can mark it like resolved?

Comment: @NgModule controls which components, pipes, directives, etc. will be loaded by your angular module as well as allowing to import other modules and use their components, pipes, directives, etc. or to export your module components, pipes, directives, etc. for other modules to use. It provides your application with modularity and reusability. In order to use any component, pipe, directive, etc. you need to first declare them in a module and you need that module to be either at the root of your application or to be imported by other modules for use. FormsModule is a module provided by angular.

Comment: Here are two more suggestions for you: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update/table-of-contents AND https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-first-look/table-of-contents The second option here is FREE this week. Otherwise you can sign up for a free week to watch any course.

Comment: Thanks, I will go for pluralsight courses.